# Why there are slight difference of total users in GA?

Tags: google-analytics

I found out that there is a slight difference in number in total user as below, but why is it so?
[image: At here Users show 1015, new user 867]

[image: But here, it shows returning visitor 234, New visitor 867 where the total should be 1101]

From the pie chart given, by calculating the total, the number of users should be 1101 instead of 1105, hope anyone can help me to clarify this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This article provides a great explanation of this discrepancy: https://www.seerinteractive.com/blog/new-users-vs-new-visitors/

> New and returning visitors are not mutually exclusive numbers, meaning that there is overlap between the two groups. If you came in as a new user during the time period being looked at, and later came back as a returning user in that same time period, then you’d appear in both the New Visitor and Returning Visitor counts. Therefore, when you sum up #3 and #4 in our visual, they don’t equal #1. That #1 is showing overall Users, with no duplicative statuses – so truly the unique count of users that came to your site during that time period.

Comment: Great find. Welcome to Webmasters SE, and thanks for your good answers since you joined!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation mbrailov, I guess the mystery solved!